# Resize a big image into a small one without constraining proportions or stretching it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

I have am image which is 1920px X 1200px. How would I make it small in such a way that it turns into a 960px X 200px exactly.

If I do it without the option of "Constraint Proportions" checked in PS, It stretches horizontally and looks very bad. If I use the option and make it 960px wide, the height becomes 600px. Again using the option and making it 200px height, makes it 320px wide.

In the below image, I need to turn it into a 960px X 200px so that apart from the above, the cows and the grass as well as the sky is visible. Atleast the cows in full, the grass from the bottom maybe clipped but not to such a extend so that the legs of the cows also get clipped and atleast some part of the sky should be visible.

I tried using crop and came up with the middle image below. The last image is stretchy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I transform images with respect to the total file size and image dimension?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/how-do-i-transform-images-with-respect-to-the-total-file-size-and-image-dimensio)

Comment: You have to make a choice.... distort, scale, or crop. Those are your options. Sometimes a combination of scale, then crop helps.

Comment: @Scott: Well I could cut/crop a lot of areas. For example a little from the bottom, some from the top and a lot of from the right. But the problem is how would I know how much to crop from each of the above sides so that it come very close to 960px X 200px without atleast much wrapping/stretching. Because all the values are given, is there a way to calculate the crop areas?

Comment: in Photoshop... select the crop tool. Enter 960 and 200 in the fields on the control bar. That'll give you the area... just move it to a place you like and hit commit.

Comment: I downloaded and looked at your original image. Because of the placement of the cows, it is physically impossible to crop this image to a 960px X 200px, *and* not cut the cows, *and* keep the sky in, *and* without stretching or squashing. The only way you can acheive all those criteria is to use Photoshop's **many** other tools to reposition the cows, edit how low the sky goes, repeat the image on one edge to extend the area, or something like that.

Comment: @DaveMG: Yeah lot's of work. Select the cows and isolate them, make them smaller, paste them up near the sky and away from the bottom grass, crop from bottom and right grass and from up sky. Maybe than it can turn into a 960px X 200px. I would be even willing to do it if i had values tellinng me how much to crop and how little to make the cows. But since no idea there, I gave up. Thanks.

Comment: Even with content awareness scaling, this image will not fit the desired format without serious problems. And with all the effort to reposition the cows, I would simply look for a different picture to save time.

Comment: @KMSTR: Yeah I am doing that just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with cropping using a saved selection. You can't generate an automatic calculation that considers how good a picture will look if you crop this or that way, so you have to do it manually:

- Create a selection that is 960px X 200px
- Choose Select > Save Selection.
- Using that selection, crop your image.

Repeat for all your images choosing the best position for your selection.